# How to match a vector of regular expression with a one string?

Tags: c++, regex, c++11, vector, stl

If I want to verify one string is completely matches with the any one in the vector of strings then i will use

```
std::find(vectOfStrings.begin(), vectOfStrings.end(), "<targetString>") != v.end()
```

If the target string matches with any of the string in the vector then it will return true.

But what if i want to check one string is matches with any one of the vector of regular expressions?
Is there any standard library i can use to make it work like 
`std::find(vectOfRegExprsns.begin(), vectOfRegExprsns.end(), "<targetString>") != v.end()`?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about using `std::find_if()` with a `lambda`?

```
std::find_if(
vectOfRegExprsns.begin(), vectOfRegExprsns.end(),
[](const std::string& item) { return regex_match(item, std::regex(targetString))});
```

Comment: Would be helpfull to read and print the result for people not familiarized with iterators